# Correct path for zerobrane torch package installtion in OSX using torch-cl?

Tags: macos, lua, torch, zerobrane

I have Zerobrane studio installed on OSX Capitan and want to add the torch package, but am unable to determine the correct placement with for torch-cl. When I try to select the Lua interpreter, torch does not appear as a choice.

I currently have it set at  path.torch = ~/Users/HOME/torch-cl/exe

Answer (score 1):

In ZeroBrane Studio go to Edit > Preferences > Settings: User and add

```
path.torch=[[/Users/yourusername/torch/install/bin/th]]
```

Note: make sure you install the latest version of ZeroBrane Studio.

Source: http://notebook.kulchenko.com/zerobrane/torch-debugging-with-zerobrane-studio